# Pico failure after powering over gpio

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

My pi pico didn't respond to bootsel and main.py also didn't work. It also don't appear as an device in thonny. Is my pi frayed to death? I was trying to power it via gpio. The voltages on vbus and vsys are right.

I tryed picoreg and it sead: Can't read CPU ID SWD connection restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can power the pi pico over GPIO (ground and VSYS).
But be very caution when powering over GPIO.
You should power off the power source before connecting or unplugging the pin .
Always plugin the ground before the VSYS, and ungplug VSYS before the ground.
Other while you will fry the board because when VSYS is still having power and no ground is connected the board will find other part to be ground and the board will be fried immediately.

Comment: Does it really matter (order of disconnecting gpio)? I thought that there would be no current, and voltage alone would not damage PI